# The implication sign of Group Closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that $x, y \in G$ implies that $xy\in G$, but does the implication go the other way as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should be more precise.  If you say "the product $xy$ is in $G$", then it seems like you've already implicitly told us that $x$ and $y$ are in $G$, simply by introducing $xy$.

Another way you might have been thinking: if $z\in G$, are there $x,y\in G$ such that $z=xy$.  This is always true: let $x=z$ and take $y$ to be the identity of the group.

Answer (score 4):

Well if $G$ is all you have, then there is no alternative to $x,y\in G$. However, for a subgroup $H<G$, taking an element $g_1g_2=h\in H$ does not mean that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are elements of $H$. For example, $g_1=g_2^{-1}$ implies that $h=1\in H$, but $g_1$ need not be in $H$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=(2\mathbb Z,+)$ then $1+3=4\in G$ but they are not member of $G$.